# Операции с матрицей и работа с вводом-выводом в файл

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-studio, файлы, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте. Дали несколько заданий на практике, одно из них следующее:
Начиная с центра, обойти по спирали все элементы квадратной матрицы А(n x m), распечатывая их в порядке обхода.
Условия по реализации:

В программе должны использоваться динамические матрицы, исходная матрица читается из текстового файла. Структура файла следующая: число строк, число столбцов, а затем идут элементы матрицы.
Например матрица 3х3 в файле:

3 3

1.1 2 3.6
5 2 2.1
2.6 8 2.0 (почему-то тут пишет в строчку, но это матрица 3х3)

Код написала, по частям работало всё, а когда стала всё собирать в одно целое с использованием функций и указателями, то запуталась окончательно, ещё и непривычно столько строчек кода видеть у себя программе. Как итог - написанный мной код не компилится и не знаю за что взяться, может кто-нибудь может глянуть и подправить его до рабочего состояния? Ещё столкнулась с тем, что писало, мол cout/cin не определены, насколько накопала в гугле - фикс этому std::.
Сам код ниже.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void PrintMatrix(double **, int, int);
int SortBySpir(double **, int, int);

int main() {
    char Filename[50];
    std::cout << "Input the name of file: ";      //запрашиваем имя файла куда будем вводить матрицу с клавиатуры
    cin >> Filename;
    ofstream out(Filename, ios_base::trunc);      //открываем и чистим файл
    ifstream in(Filename);
    if (!in)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
        std::system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    double** matr;
    int n, m;
    std::cout << "Enter size of matr ";        //вводим кратность квадратной матрицы, так что n должно быть равно m
    in >> n;
    in >> m;
    matr = new double*[n];                     //заполняем матрицу с клавиатуры сразу в файл
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)
        {
             in >> matr[i][j];
        }
    }  
PrintMatrix(matr, n, m);
SortBySpir(matr, n, m);
std::cout << endl << endl << "After sort" << endl << endl;
PrintMatrix(matr, n, m);
in.close();

char nameOutputFile[40];
std::cout << "Input the name of output file: ";        //файл в который будем выводить матрицу после сортировки
cin >> nameOutputFile;
ofstream out(nameOutputFile);
if (!out)
{
    std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    std::system("pause");
    exit(1);
}
int i, j;
out << n << " " << m << endl;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)                        //выводим матрицу
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        out.width(8);
        out << matr[i][j];
    }
    out << endl;
}
out.close();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                     //освобождаем память
{
    delete[] matr[i];
}
delete[] matr;
std::system("pause");
return 0;
}

    void PrintMatrix(double** a, int n, int m){                //функция для вывода матрицы
        std::cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        std::cout.precision(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                std::cout.width(8);
                std::cout << a[i][j];
            }
            std::cout << endl;
        }
    }

    int SortBySpir(double** a, int n, int m) {       //алгоритм который нашла и попыталась видоизменить под свою программу. Работает только с матрицами нечётной кратности.
        int z;                      //счётчик 
        int i = n / 2; int j = m / 2;       //устанавливаем итераторы на центральный элемент массива
                                        //цикл обхода по спирали по часовой стрелке 
        do {
            z++;//увеличиваем величину сдвига на 1
            for (int k = 0; k<z; k++)//выводим n элементов со сдвигом вверх
                std::cout << a[i--][j] << ' ';
            //точка выхода из цикла
            if (z == n)//если сдвиг равен размерности массива
                break;//выход
            for (int k = 0; k<z; k++)//выводим n элементов со сдвигом вправо
                std::cout << a[i][j++] << ' ';
            n++;//опять увеличиваем сдвиг
            for (int k = 0; k<z; k++)////выводим n элементов со сдвигом вниз
                std::cout << a[i++][j] << ' ';
            for (int k = 0; k<z; k++)////выводим n элементов со сдвигом влево
                std::cout << a[i][j--] << ' ';

        } while (z);
        std::system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

UPD: Скрин ошибок при компиляции
http://prntscr.com/cqk6tq

Answer (score 1):

память не выделена.

```
matr = new double*[n];                      
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)
    {
         in >> matr[i][j];//откуда взялось j? Может выделить сначала память?!
    }
}
```

Приложи скрины ошибок.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cqk6tq

Comment: @Anya1919 как по мне, проблема все таки с созданием матрицы http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread262013.html

Comment: А что можете сказать по поводу ошибок, которые в скриншоте приложены?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка номер раз. Вместо

> `matr = new double*[n];`

пишите

```
matr = new double[n][m];
```

удаление, в принципе, работать будет, но так

```
delete[][] matr;
```

будет красивее

Дальше было бы здорово, если бы Вы указали какая именно ошибка компиляции появляется и на какой строке?

Comment: matr = new double[n][m]; так разве можно? http://ideone.com/mLAELq

Comment: Можно. Если Вам не нужна матрица с разным количеством столбцов в строках

Comment: При инициализации вида matr = new double[m][n] - [n] подчёркивает красным и говорит что выражение должно иметь константное значение.
Если ничего не менять, то при компиляции выдаёт следующие ошибки, в скриншоте http://prntscr.com/cqk6tq